# How to select a specific element in a dropdown menu using python3?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, select, drop-down-menu

Sorry about my question in case it is a duplicate. I searched and tried to implement what I found about my problem, but couldn't find something that worked for my case.
So here it is: I'm trying to click on a specific element in a dropdown menu. The html of the dropdown menu is like this:

```
</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="td col15">
                            <div>
                                Cantone
                            </div>
                            <div class="RadAjaxPanel" id="ctl00_MainContent_ctl00_MainContent_ddl_cantonsPanel">
        <div id="ctl00_MainContent_ddl_cantons" class="RadComboBox RadComboBox_Default" style="width:160px;">
            <table summary="combobox" style="border-width:0;border-collapse:collapse;">
                <tr class="rcbReadOnly">
                    <td class="rcbInputCell rcbInputCellLeft" style="width:100%;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$ddl_cantons" type="text" class="rcbInput radPreventDecorate" id="ctl00_MainContent_ddl_cantons_Input" value="" readonly="readonly" /></td><td class="rcbArrowCell rcbArrowCellRight"><a id="ctl00_MainContent_ddl_cantons_Arrow" style="overflow: hidden;display: block;position: relative;outline: none;">select</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table><div class="rcbSlide" style="z-index:6000;"><div id="ctl00_MainContent_ddl_cantons_DropDown" class="RadComboBoxDropDown RadComboBoxDropDown_Default " style="display:none;"><div class="rcbScroll rcbWidth" style="width:100%;"><ul class="rcbList" style="list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;zoom:1;"><li class="rcbItem"></li><li class="rcbItem">AG</li><li class="rcbItem">AI</li><li class="rcbItem">AR</li><li class="rcbItem">BE</li><li class="rcbItem">BL</li><li class="rcbItem">BS</li><li class="rcbItem">FR</li><li class="rcbItem">GE</li><li class="rcbItem">GL</li><li class="rcbItem">GR</li><li class="rcbItem">JU</li><li class="rcbItem">LU</li><li class="rcbItem">NE</li><li class="rcbItem">NW</li><li class="rcbItem">OW</li><li class="rcbItem">SG</li><li class="rcbItem">SH</li><li class="rcbItem">SO</li><li class="rcbItem">SZ</li><li class="rcbItem">TG</li><li class="rcbItem">TI</li><li class="rcbItem">UR</li><li class="rcbItem">VD</li><li class="rcbItem">VS</li><li class="rcbItem">ZG</li><li class="rcbItem">ZH</li></ul></div></div></div><input id="ctl00_MainContent_ddl_cantons_ClientState" name="ctl00_MainContent_ddl_cantons_ClientState" type="hidden" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried the code below, but it is getting the wrong click for some elements (and the right one for a few other elements) In other words it is not a very precise select. Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

# Open the website in chrome
url = 'http://www.asca.ch/Partners.aspx?lang=it'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

# Click the dropdown
cantone = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_ddl_cantons_Input"]""")
cantone.click()

#find all canotenes in the dropdown list. Omit the first empty entry.
dropdown_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//div[@id='ctl00_MainContent_ddl_cantons_DropDown']/div/ul[@class='rcbList']/li[@class='rcbItem']""")

cantone_list=[]
for l in dropdown_list:
cantone_list.append(l.text)

cantone.send_keys("AI")
cantone.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

In my code I'm trying to click the first element found (AI), but instead of AI it selects AG. I don't know what I am doing wrong.
Some help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below code.

```
dropdown_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='ctl00_MainContent_ddl_cantons_DropDown']/div/ul[@class='rcbList']/li")
print(len(dropdown_list))
for l in range(len(dropdown_list)):

  if "AI" in dropdown_list[l].text:
     time.sleep(1)
     dropdown_list[l].click()
     break
```

Comment: Thank you Kajal, but it clicked on AR. Is it anything wrong in my webdriver (chrome)?

Comment: @JamalHajjar: webdriver is too fast that is why it is selecting next element i have given 1 second wait.try now this should work.

Comment: Thank A LOT Kajal! The time.sleep did the trick. You're the man!

Comment: Perhaps `time.sleep(1)` is against all the best practices and these answers are prone to downvotes as they won't be useful to future readers.

Comment: @DebanjanB: I know it is against the best practices.However the problem is there when user looping through the element and in that case i have provided  1 second time.sleep.If you have any other option i am glad to know that.Thanks.

Comment: @KajalKundu We have already seen your suggesting _WebDriverWait_ in your answers. Not sure why you skipped _WebDriverWait_ specifically answering this question.

Comment: @DebanjanB, I know  WebDriverWait but here how you slowdown a loop that what my question to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select "AI" just add this step.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='ctl00_MainContent_ddl_cantons_DropDown']//li[.='AI']").click()
```

This will select the "AI" directly and efficiently.